# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory – Python won't accept a variable when trying to rename files

Tags: python, directory, file-rename

Given a directory with 1000 files, I want to move every file beginning with a certain letter into a new directory, which is given the name of that letter.

I have everything working up until I'm renaming the files to move them to the new directory.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import os 

character = raw_input("Enter a character: ") # will be name of new directory

if not os.path.exists("p6_files/" + character): # if the directory doesn't already exist
    os.mkdir("p6_files/" + character) # makes empty directory
    directory = sorted(os.listdir("p6_files")) # sorts p6_files by first letter
    for word in directory:
        if word[0] == character: # for each word starting with character ...
          os.rename(word, "p6_files/"+character+"/"+word)
        else:
            pass
else:
    print "That already exists!"
```

However when I run this code I get this error:
**OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

It seems that it doesn't recognize **word** as a file or directory since it's a variable.

I know that os.rename wants strings, but I believe that each word is a string?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There might be a problem with absolute vs relative paths...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to add the directory name back onto the file

```
for word in directory:
    if word[0] == character: # for each word starting with character ...
      os.rename(os.path.join(directory, word), "p6_files/"+character+"/"+word)
    else:
        pass
```

This is a classic example of the benefits of print statement debugging. In your original code, you could change `os.rename(os.path.join(directory, word), "p6_files/"+character+"/"+word)` to `print(os.path.join(directory, word), "p6_files/"+character+"/"+word)` and see the the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. The main change was adding `"p6files/"` at the beginning of `word` in `os.rename()`. I also just limited the input to one character and used a list comprehension to simplify some logic.

```
import os 

character = raw_input("Enter a character: ")[0]

if not os.path.exists("p6_files/" + character):
    os.mkdir("p6_files/" + character)
    files = [file for file in os.listdir("p6_files") if file[0] == character]
    for word in files:
        os.rename("p6_files/"+word, "p6_files/"+character+"/"+word)
else:
    print "That already exists!"
```

Comment: when I do this I get this error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.

Comment: any idea what that means?

Comment: @Evan Maybe you should use ```os.path.join()``` instead of ```"p6_files/" + …```. By the way, are you using Windows?